# Turning an array into a hash

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a ruby array of hashes:

```
my_array = [{"apples" => 5}, {"oranges" => 12}]
```

I would like to turn it into a hash, where the hash keys are equal to the array index values +1, so like this:

```
my_hash = {"1"=>{"apples"=> 5}, "2"=>{"oranges" => 12}}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `my_array.each_with_index.map{|elem, idx| [idx + 1, elem]}.to_h`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `to_s` will do the same trick in your case :)

Comment: @LukasBaliak: string keys might be a mistake to begin with :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
my_array = [{"apples" => 5}, {"oranges" => 12}]
my_hash = my_array.each_with_index.map{|h, i| [(i+1).to_s,  h]}.to_h
```

Comment: You're too late!

Answer (score 5):

You can also [Enumerable#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) with a range, then convert [Array#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Array.html#method-i-to_h):

```
(1..my_array.size).zip(my_array).to_h
#=> {1=>{"apples"=>5}, 2=>{"oranges"=>12}}
```

---

### How it works

`my_array.size #=> 2` returns the size of the Array as an Integer.

`(1..my_array.size)` it's an inclusive [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Range.html) which enumerates **integers** form `1` to array size, `2` in this case.

A Range responds to [Enumerable#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip), so, for example you can do this obtaining an Array of pairs:

```
(1..3).zip(:a..:c) #=> [[1, :a], [2, :b], [3, :c]]
```

Finally, an Array of pairs can be converted into an Hash, see [Array#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Array.html#method-i-to_h):

```
[[1, :a], [2, :b], [3, :c]].to_h #=> {1=>:a, 2=>:b, 3=>:c}
```

Since the Range is made of integer, keys of the Hash are integer. But you can tweak the line of code to obtain strings as keys.

Comment: Can you explain this solution, please. I am trying to see if I can modify it to produce a hash key that's a string, instead of an integer, as is the case here

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper, I edited with an explanation, hope it is clear. I didn't add a solution for getting keys as String, but if you need a suggestion, just post back.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use [Enumerator#with_index](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index) to have index and [Enumerator#each_with_object](https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object) to create new hash

```
my_array = [{"apples"=> 5}, {"oranges" => 12}]
my_hash = my_array.each.with_index.with_object({}){|(hsh, i), e| e[(i+1).to_s] = hsh}
# => {"1"=>{"apples"=> 5}, "2"=>{"oranges" => 12}}
```

Comment: Also try `my_array.each.with_index.with_object` for a tiny bit more consistency